# Visualforce Page Properties

Tags: visualforce

I created a visualforce page and placed it in the page layout I want it to display in.
The visualforce section appears cutoff and I played around with the Properties by changing the width and height of the page - nothing seems to work.

Additionally, an entire date field is not displaying on the VF Page.

When I preview the page - it looks good. Currently, I have the width at 100% and height at 2000%. I did try various other combinations - doesnt seem to be working.

Can someone please help me!!

Here's the screenshot how the VF page appears:

[image]

Comment: can you provide code of you VF page? It would be easy to debug

Answer (score 4):

There's two problems here. We shall address both of them.

First, your page is overflowing horizontally (to the right) because you have too many fields for the browser to display the fields at the requested sizes. Date fields take up extra space because of the "today" link to the right of each. Use fewer columns in your pageBlockSection/pageBlockTable/dataTable/panel/etc (however you're rendering the fields), or use `<apex:input type="date">`, although be aware you'll have to figure out how to feature-detect if the browser provides a built-in date widget when using this data type.

Second, you can't specify percentages for your embedded page height. The height attribute only works correctly when you specify the number of *pixels* you'd like to use. It looks like Salesforce internally translated your 2,000% into a decimal value, which would be 20 pixels. You'd probably get a bigger box if you specified something like 20000%, but that's really just getting silly. Use whole numbers instead of percentages.

Comment: <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyle="width:15%" labelStyle="width:5%">
        <apex:outputLabel >Cmpl Dt</apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Delivery_to_PBM_4_Completion_Date__c}" style="width:200px"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

Comment: Thats what I am doing to display my code. Would it be possible for you to help me fix it so that it displays on the browser?